# The use of the definite article in place of the indefinte one in context

Tags: articles

It was in this [video](https://youtu.be/KyVSuI6JyOs). It is at 15 minute and 21 second. Here is the context:

> So I am not **the** anti weed guy, I am **the** pro logic guy.

I am confused because there was no mentioning of any anti weed guys in the video before he said it. Would it make more sense if he said *I am not an anti weed...*? Did he use *the* for emphasis?

Comment: I believe you have been told before that  "previous mention" is just one of the many contexts where the definite article is used. It is not *the* context, that is, the only context.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: Excellently illustrative comment! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincidentally (or maybe not, since the video was only posted on Youtube a week ago, so it's "current") I happened to watch that same TED talk post myself last night. The speaker *could* have used ***indefinite*** articles *(**an** anti-weed guy, **a** pro-logic guy)*, but in context there's a subtle extra implication to his actual choice.

Saying ***the*** in such contexts more strongly suggests that both the speaker and his audience (and society at large, in fact) all share ***the same*** clear-cut image of what they suppose(d) the/a stereotypical "anti-weed" person to be like (i.e. - ***the*** archetypal example, not just one of many).

Since a big part of the speaker's message is ***the sterotypical image many of us share is wrong or misleading***, it's very appropriate to "subliminally" call attention to that through his choice of article. He's a very good "persuasive" public speaker, and that subtle choice encourages his audience to feel that they and the speaker are "on the same side, thinking the same things".